# Using sass in a phoenix project that runs in dokku

Tags: node.js, phoenix-framework, dokku, npm-install

I added sass to a fresh phoenix project.

Like so:

1. add `"sass-brunch": ">= 1.9"` to package.json
2. rename app.css to app.sass
3. - remove {, }, and ; from sass file, and check *to check that everything is valid sass*.

It works locally, but when I push up the project to a dokku installation it gets stuck at

```
You need to have Sass on your system
Execute `gem install sass`
```

which is weird to me - I thought it'd be installed when npm-install is run, because I do have it added in the package.json

And then it stucks at

```
10 Jan 15:02:11 - info: compiling
```

My current package.json

```
{
  "repository": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.0",
    "brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "clean-css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "javascript-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "uglify-js-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "sass-brunch": ">= 1.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

Any clues?
My next step is that I'll try n' see if I can log into that specific app and manually install that gem, but there must be a better way?

Now when I try to push the app again, it's stuck at that point

`remote: phoenix is currently being deployed or locked. Waiting...` :\

**Update**
" it appears Dokku locks by creating an empty hidden file: [/home/dokku/app/.build.lock](https://coderwall.com/p/vhmlwa/dokku-remote-app-is-locked) I simply deleted this file and I was able to deploy again. " 
So ssh into dokku@your-page or root@your-page, whatever you have setup - `cd /home/dokku/app-name/` and then (optional: you can first run `ls -la` to see that .build.lock is there) run `rm .build.lock`
now you should be able to push again.)

**Update**
Manually installing sass gem didn't help.

---

### **Update**

Looked at the [known issues for dokku list](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues). I found no mentioning of sass, css or assets.

**uname -a**
`Linux maleficent 3.13.0-71-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 1 02:34:22 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**free -m**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           994        885        108         21         89        111
-/+ buffers/cache:        684        309
Swap:         2047        461       1586
```

**docker version**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**docker -D info**

```
Containers: 23
Images: 131
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 177
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-71-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 994 MiB
Name: maleficent
ID: JD4N:6BHQ:NUG6:BLP2:VTW5:LRIH:UY35:6GEL:OXQH:2AEK:O6OO:A3SM
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

**docker run --rm -ti gliderlabs/herokuish:latest herokuish version**

```
herokuish: 0.3.5
buildpacks:
  heroku-buildpack-clojure   v70
  heroku-buildpack-go        v18
  heroku-buildpack-gradle    v12
  heroku-buildpack-grails    v19
  heroku-buildpack-java      v40
  heroku-buildpack-multi     26fa21a
  heroku-buildpack-nodejs    v86
  heroku-buildpack-php       v80
  heroku-buildpack-play      v24
  heroku-buildpack-python    v70
  heroku-buildpack-ruby      v140
  heroku-buildpack-scala     v63
  https://github.com/dokku/buildpack-nginx v5
```

**dokku version**

```
0.4.6
```

**dokku plugin**

```
  00_dokku-standard    0.4.0 enabled    dokku core standard plugin
  20_events            0.4.0 enabled    dokku core events logging plugin
  apps                 0.4.0 enabled    dokku core apps plugin
  backup               0.4.0 enabled    dokku core backup plugin
  build-env            0.4.0 enabled    dokku core build-env plugin
  certs                0.4.0 enabled    dokku core certificate management plugin
  checks               0.4.0 enabled    dokku core checks plugin
  common               0.4.0 enabled    dokku core common plugin
  config               0.4.0 enabled    dokku core config plugin
  docker-options       0.4.0 enabled    dokku core docker-options plugin
  domains              0.4.0 enabled    dokku core domains plugin
  enter                0.4.0 enabled    dokku core enter plugin
  git                  0.4.0 enabled    dokku core git plugin
  logs                 0.4.0 enabled    dokku core logs plugin
  mysql                1.0.0 enabled    dokku mysql service plugin
  named-containers     0.4.0.1 enabled    dokku core named containers plugin
  nginx-vhosts         0.4.0 enabled    dokku core nginx-vhosts plugin
  plugin               0.4.0 enabled    dokku core plugin plugin
  postgres             1.0.0 enabled    dokku postgres service plugin
  ps                   0.4.0 enabled    dokku core ps plugin
  shell                0.4.0 enabled    dokku core shell plugin
  tags                 0.4.0 enabled    dokku core tags plugin
  tar                  0.4.0 enabled    dokku core tar plugin
```

VPS details: 1 GB Memory / 30 GB Disk

**Update**
Swap file added. Didn't make any difference.
Output freezes here:

```
...
       lcid@1.0.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/lcid
       invert-kv@1.0.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/invert-kv
       window-size@0.1.4 /tmp/build/node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/window-size
       y18n@3.2.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/y18n
       progeny@0.5.2 /tmp/build/node_modules/progeny
       fs-mode@1.0.1 /tmp/build/node_modules/fs-mode
       cbify@1.0.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/cbify
       fn-args@1.0.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/fn-args
       promise@6.1.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/promise
       asap@1.0.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/asap
       ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 /tmp/build/node_modules/ecc-jsbn
       jsbn@0.1.0 /tmp/build/node_modules/jsbn
       jodid25519@1.0.2 /tmp/build/node_modules/jodid25519
       tweetnacl@0.13.3 /tmp/build/node_modules/tweetnacl
       npm WARN package.json @ No license field.
       Running default compile
       You need to have Sass on your system
       Execute `gem install sass`
       11 Jan 20:49:49 - info: compiling
```

Comment: If you can provide all the information the dokku project normally asks for from [here](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#reporting-other-issues) in this stackoverflow question, it might help better debug what is going on. If the node compilation step is just "stuck", you might need more memory on your server (you can [enable swap](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-installation/#vms-with-less-than-1gb-of-memory)).

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez memory swap has been activated. Looking at what is usually asked for.

Comment: Or atleast I thouht I had that on, becuase I did sth earlier which I thought  activated swap - because the "normal" assets compilations was failing before.

Comment: Maybe related? https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static/issues/12

Comment: Any difference if you configure sass-brunch to use "native" instead of "ruby" per https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-brunch? My deploys seem to use node-sass and not Ruby.

Comment: Maybe your node asset manager starts a webserver and doesn't kill it? I'd be curious to see what happens on heroku, since we don't really do anything special here...

Comment: @henrik-n where are those "options" suppose to be added? I don't understand that at all.
(Regarding: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-brunch)

Comment: @Alisso No idea, sorry, haven't used that myself.

Comment: @Alisso Hey I deployed Phoenix and SASS to my Dokku instance yesterday, and remembered this thread. Do you still need help? How does your buildpack look like?

Comment: @Wobbley, I remember giving up. Where/How do I know what my buildpack looks like? :)

Comment: Do you have a .buildpacks file in the root of your project? Which guide were you using again to set up dokku? Looks to me like you are running it as a Node.js server? If you have given up and don't want to use SASS that's fine too :)

Comment: @Wobbley I set it up as a dokku droplet.  :)
There it is (the .buildpacks file). It contains:
```https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir.git``` 
```https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static.git```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, a bit messy, but it works!

**Add Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'sass'
```

**run**

```
bundle install
```

(to generate Gemfile.lock).
(`gem install bundler`, to get access to bundle )

**Add ruby buildpack to buildpacks:**
in file .buildpacks add

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

...at the top of the file (!)

Save, push, works!  :D  *happy dance*

Helpful: https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static